# ClockWorkMod Recovery doesn't support my phone model

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid

I want to create a nandroid backup of my phone and so I've installed the latest version of the Rom Manager, but when I want to install custom recovery (ClockWorkMod) in the 'Confirm Phone Model' screen the two listed phones are not same as my phone model (mine is Galaxy Ace 3 Gt-s7272)

What should I do? Choose one of the listed models? Is there any danger in doing that?

[image]

Comment: Try the unsupported device option. In the meantime, I will try to get you an official link.